Doing the characteristic polynomial I can't move forward, where do I fail?
I have this problem: Consider the following system of equations
$$
\begin{align*}
y_{1}'(t) &= y_{3}, \\
y_{2}'(t) &= -3y_{1}, \\
y_{3}'(t) &= \alpha y_{1} + 2y_{2} - y_{3}.
\end{align*}
$$
For which values of the parameter $\alpha$ the zero solution is asymptotically stable?
What I do is a $3 \times 3$ matrix, and then, I obtain the following characteristic polynomial: $-\lambda^3-\lambda^2+\alpha\lambda-6=0$, which does not have easy-finding solutions. For that reason, I think I am doing something wrong. Could anyone help me, please?

No, looks fine. The closed forms for $\lambda$ are a bit complicated but the cubic can be solved. On the other hand, it's possible one of the right sides of the given equations has a typo. If for instance $y_1'=y_2$ instead of $y_3$, the characteristic polynomial becomes much simpler.

you can use RH-test on the polynomial  like you noted in another question.

Quoting from Wikipedia: "The third-order polynomial $P(s)=s^3+a_2s^2+a_1s+a_0$ has all roots in the open left half-plane if and only if $a_2, a_1,$ and $a_0$ are positive and $a_2a_1>a_0$."

Based on the state matrix $\mathbf{A}$
$$ \left[\matrix{\dot{y}_{1} \cr \dot{y}_{2} \cr \dot{y}_{3}}\right] = \underbrace{\left[\matrix{0 & 0 & 1 \cr -3 & 0 & 0 \cr \alpha & 2 & -1}\right]}_{\text{state matrix } \mathbf{A}} \left[\matrix{y_{1} \cr y_{2} \cr y_{3}}\right] $$
you have successfully obtained the characteristic polynomial
$$ p_{\mathbf{A}}(\lambda) = \underbrace{1}_{a_{3}} \lambda^3 \underbrace{+ 1}_{a_{2}} \lambda^2 \underbrace{- \alpha}_{a_{1}} \lambda \underbrace{+ 6}_{a_{0}} .$$
As suggested by other users, the next step is to either conduct the Routh–Hurwitz stability analysis or directly apply the inequality formula, $a_{2} a_{1} > a_{0}$.
However, if this is a homework assignment, it is likely that you are expected to compute the entries in the Routh–Hurwitz array. If you construct the array correctly, you will obtain the following array:
$$ \begin{array}{c|c|c}
 \lambda^3 & 1 & -\alpha   \\\hline
 \lambda^2 & 1 & 6 \\\hline
 \lambda^1 & - \alpha - 6 & 0 \\\hline
 \lambda^0 & \frac{6 \alpha + 36}{\alpha + 6} & 0 
\end{array} $$
The final step is to apply the Routh–Hurwitz criterion to determine the gain $\alpha$ that ensures exponential stability.
Note: The Routh-Hurwitz criterion states that the number of roots of $p_{\mathbf{A}}(\lambda)$ with positive real parts should match the number of sign changes in the first column of the Routh-Hurwitz array. In simpler terms, this criterion requires the absence of sign changes in the first column for a system to be stable. This condition is considered both necessary and sufficient.
